# openshift form sendgrid ajax form html5 PHP BootStrap

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, openshift

I am trying to use an HTML form on openshift. The form controlled by Ajax. I can successfully send from OpenShift using a seperate page for the form, but I would like to use the BootStrap form. Bootstrap template is freelancer at [Start BootStrap](http://startbootstrap.com)

I tried replacing the sendgrid code where the send php command was and moved return true to the end of the file.

working now-I must have had something wrong in my configuration. leaving here in case someone else wants to get a form working with openshift and sendgrid.

```html
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 

 
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'xxxx'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
//mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);


// use actual sendgrid username and password in this section
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
$user = 'xxxxx'; // place SG username here
$pass = 'xxxxx'; // place SG password here

// grabs HTML form's post data; if you customize the form.html parameters then you will need to reference their new new names here
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['phone']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];


// note the above parameters now referenced in the 'subject', 'html', and 'text' sections
// make the to email be your own address or where ever you would like the contact form info sent
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "xxxxx", // set TO address to have the contact form's email content sent to
    'subject'   => "Contact Form Submission", // Either give a subject for each submission, or set to $subject
    'html'      => "<html><head><title> Contact Form</title><body>
    Name: $name\n<br>
    Email: $email\n<br>
    Subject: $subject\n<br>
    Message: $message <body></title></head></html>", // Set HTML here.  Will still need to make sure to reference post data names
    'text'      => "
    Name: $name\n
    Email: $email\n
    Subject: $subject\n
    $message",
    'from'      => "xxxxxx", // set from address here, it can really be anything
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
return true;   
?>
```

contact_me php from bootstrap theme

```js
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
 
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;   
?>
```

The working mailer.php

```html
<?php
// use actual sendgrid username and password in this section
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
$user = 'xxxxx'; // place SG username here
$pass = 'xxxxx'; // place SG password here

// grabs HTML form's post data; if you customize the form.html parameters then you will need to reference their new new names here
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];


// note the above parameters now referenced in the 'subject', 'html', and 'text' sections
// make the to email be your own address or where ever you would like the contact form info sent
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "xxxxx", // set TO address to have the contact form's email content sent to
    'subject'   => "Contact Form Submission", // Either give a subject for each submission, or set to $subject
    'html'      => "<html><head><title> Contact Form</title><body>
    Name: $name\n<br>
    Email: $email\n<br>
    Subject: $subject\n<br>
    Message: $message <body></title></head></html>", // Set HTML here.  Will still need to make sure to reference post data names
    'text'      => "
    Name: $name\n
    Email: $email\n
    Subject: $subject\n
    $message",
    'from'      => "xxxxxxxx", // set from address here, it can really be anything
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// Redirect to thank you page upon successfull completion, will want to build one if you don't alreday have one available
header('Location: thanks.html'); // feel free to use whatever title you wish for thank you landing page, but will need to reference that file name in place of the present 'thanks.html'
exit();

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

the ajax file from the bootstrap template

```js
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                   // $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

The bootstrap index.html form

```html
 <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->
                    <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Message</label>
                                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me. The script works as is! I am not sure why it was not working, but I must have somehow corrupted my installation. I am leaving this up in case someone else wants to get emails working with openshift.